# Existence of an Analytic functions und

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist an analytic function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}$ such that $f\left(\frac{1} {2n}\right)$= $f\left(\frac{1} {2n+1}\right)$=$\left(\frac{1} {2n}\right)$  for all $n\geq 1$ ?

Comment: Hint: Identity principle.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $g(z)=f(z)-z$. Then 
$$g\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)=0$$

What does the identity theorem tells you?

What is $g\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$?

Answer (score 0):

No. Obviously $f(0) = 0$ (by continuity), and then the modulus of an analytic function has to be strictly monotonic on the positive real line close to zero (consider the first nonzero coefficient in the taylor series). But your function fails to be monotonic.